# Why is $-32^{\frac{1}{5}} = 2$

Tags: exponentiation, factoring

When you factorize $-32$, you get:

$-32 = (-16) \cdot 2$

$-16 = (-8) \cdot 2$

$-8 = (-4) \cdot 2$

$-4 = (-2) \cdot 2$

$-32^{\frac{1}{5}} = -2$

The reason I am asking is because you get $-4 = -2 \cdot 2$ where all along we have been multiplying by positive 2 which would lead me to believe that $-32^{\frac{1}{5}}$ $ = 2$; but that is not so - then I got to thinking: Is $-2$ positive or negative? I.e. the 2 that we were multiplying to get $-16, -32$, etc.

That is my question, maybe it should be rephrased because I dont know all the terminology so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try multiplying by $-2$ instead of $2$ in the above steps. You will get the same result.

Comment: You should be careful when writing exponent over negative numbers. Try to use parenthesis because $-32^x$ can be interpreted as $-(32^x)$ or $(-32)^x$.

Comment: As you've written 

$-32=(-16)\cdot 2=\dots=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot 2\cdot (-2)$

but $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot 2=(-2)\cdot(-2)\cdot(-2)\cdot (-2)=(-2)^4$, since you have even number of multiplicands then it follows that 

$-32=(-2)^5\implies-32^{1/5}=-2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that 
$$-(32^\frac15)=-(2^{5\cdot\frac15})=-2$$ And $$(-32)^\frac15=(-2)^{5\cdot\frac15}=-2$$

I hope your doubt is resolved now.

Comment: yes, thanks!! It was very simple, yet I couldnt see it.

Answer (score 5):

$$-32^{\frac{1}{5}}=(-32)^{\frac{1}{5}}=(-2)^{{5}^{\frac{1}{5}}}=(-2)^{5\cdot \frac{1}{5}}=-2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(-2)\cdot(-2)\cdot(-2)\cdot(-2)\cdot(-2)=-32$$
Then
$$(-2)^5=-32 \Rightarrow -32^{\frac15}=-\sqrt[5]{32}=-2$$

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows that factorizationis not agood way to find the $n-$rooth of a negative integer number, because the **factorization of negative number is not unique** (as it is for positive integers).

Also excuding the factor $-1$, you have:
$$
-32=(-2)(2)^4=(-2)^3(2)^2=(-2)^5
$$
and always the last factorization gives a number such that its $5-$power is $-32$.